# Facebook like button/box causing "Stop running this script" errors in IE8

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

In the last 24 hours most of our websites that have Facebook like buttons or like boxes have started showing the following error only in Internet Explorer 8 and below:

> Stop running this script?
>
> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it
>   continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

It only seems to happen with some variations of the like button, particularly the standard type, and on the like box.

I have tried disabling most of the other scripts on our websites but it's only after I disable the Facebook script that the error goes away.

Here's an example of one page that it's happening on:
http://entertainment.wsi.tafensw.edu.au/

Is there any known issues with Facebook widgets and IE8 in the last 24 hours, or any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: I have also found a few other websites with Facebook widgets that are exhibiting the same problem. I have tried on various computers and networks.

Comment: Some websites with Facebook widgets seem to have the same problem, but many don't... Not sure why?

Comment: This is being tracked at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/669917143021665 - please subscribe if you are still having issues.

Comment: Facebook have now fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we had the same issue on website. It started to happen from yesterday 04/07/2013. It only happens in IE7 browser. We just omitted the browser from showing the Like box with below code.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") == -1) {            
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);     
    }
```

Comment: FYI - It seems facebook has stop supporting IE7 browser.

Comment: Our issue is happening on IE8 too, but this seems like a good solution anyway, at least temporarily.

Comment: It seems that excluding the Facebook script on IE7 is the only solution at the moment at least. Thanks.

Comment: This is being tracked at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/669917143021665 - please subscribe if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue on several sites. Changing the layout of the button works on Vista ( IE8 ), but not on WinXP (IE8). 
Win7 PC's with IE > 8 work fine.
Our only solution was to disable the script for now and keep a backup so we can restore it fast when FB fixes this annoyance.
Any suggestions welcome to get it working anyway are more then welcome.